# Pandas: apply operation to repetitive columns in MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have MultiColumns: the second level repetitively contains `Job Openings` and `Hires`. I would like to subtract one from another for each of the top-level columns - but all I try gets me into index-errors or slice errors. How can I compute it?

Sample data:

```
>>> df.head()
Out[25]: 
           Total nonfarm              Total private               
                   Hires Job openings         Hires Job openings   
date                                                               
2001-01-01          5777         5385          5419         4887   
2002-01-01          4849         3759          4539         3381   
2003-01-01          4971         3824          4645         3424   
2004-01-01          4827         3459          4552         3153   
2005-01-01          5207         3670          4876         3358
```

expected output:

```
Out[25]: 
           Total nonfarm   Total private              
              difference      difference   
date                                                               
2001-01-01          1234            5678          
2002-01-01          1234            5678          
2003-01-01          1234            5678         
2004-01-01          1234            5678      
2005-01-01          1234            5678
```

where the numbers obviously are not correct.

#### Specifically within an apply()

In order to have a generally applicable way, I was trying to set up

```
def apply(group):
    result = group.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, 'Job openings']].div(group.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, 'Hires']].values)
    result.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[group.columns.get_level_values(0)[0]], ['Ratio']])
    return result.values
foo = df.groupby(axis=1, level=0).apply(apply)
```

Which suffers from two problems:

- I need to cheat around with `.values` in order to get the divide properly
- `foo` is not a proper dataframe:

  Accommodation and food services                    [[0.76], [0.480349344978], [0.501388888889], [...
  Arts, entertainment, and recreation                [[0.558139534884], [0.46017699115], [0.2483221...
  Construction                                       [[0.35], [0.274881516588], [0.267260579065], [...

I first tried to return `result`, instead of `result.values`, but that just lead to a data frame full of `NaN`

#### Specifically with using the column names

What I don't like about the highest-voted answer is that it requires on `.diff()` or `.div()` - hacks, which make the code hard to read and are hard to implement when there's more than two columns at the sub-level.

Answer (score 4):

#### Setup

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [5777, 5385, 5419, 4887],
        [4849, 3759, 4539, 3381],
        [4971, 3824, 4645, 3424],
        [4827, 3459, 4552, 3153],
        [5207, 3670, 4876, 3358],
    ],
    index=pd.to_datetime(['2001-01-01',
                          '2002-01-01',
                          '2003-01-01',
                          '2004-01-01',
                          '2005-01-01']),
    columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
        [('Total nonfarm', 'Hires'), ('Total nonfarm', 'Job Openings'),
         ('Total private', 'Hires'), ('Total private', 'Job Openings')]
    )
)

print df

           Total nonfarm              Total private             
                   Hires Job Openings         Hires Job Openings
2001-01-01          5777         5385          5419         4887
2002-01-01          4849         3759          4539         3381
2003-01-01          4971         3824          4645         3424
2004-01-01          4827         3459          4552         3153
2005-01-01          5207         3670          4876         3358
```

Try:

```
df.T.groupby(level=0).diff(-1).dropna().T

           Total nonfarm Total private
                   Hires         Hires
2001-01-01         392.0         532.0
2002-01-01        1090.0        1158.0
2003-01-01        1147.0        1221.0
2004-01-01        1368.0        1399.0
2005-01-01        1537.0        1518.0
```

To apply other transforms, say a ratio, you could do:

```
print df.T.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: np.exp(np.log(x).diff(-1))).dropna().T

           Total nonfarm Total private
                   Hires         Hires
2001-01-01      1.072795      1.108860
2002-01-01      1.289971      1.342502
2003-01-01      1.299948      1.356600
2004-01-01      1.395490      1.443704
2005-01-01      1.418801      1.452055
```

Or:

```
print df.T.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.div(x.shift(-1))).dropna().T

           Total nonfarm Total private
                   Hires         Hires
2001-01-01      1.072795      1.108860
2002-01-01      1.289971      1.342502
2003-01-01      1.299948      1.356600
2004-01-01      1.395490      1.443704
2005-01-01      1.418801      1.452055
```

To rename columns and combine with the original dataframe you can:

```
df2 = df.T.groupby(level=0).diff(-1).dropna().T
df2.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
    [('Total nonfarm', 'difference'),
     ('Total private', 'difference')])
pd.concat([df, df2], axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
```

Looks like:

```
           Total nonfarm                         Total private               \
                   Hires Job Openings difference         Hires Job Openings   
2001-01-01          5777         5385      392.0          5419         4887   
2002-01-01          4849         3759     1090.0          4539         3381   
2003-01-01          4971         3824     1147.0          4645         3424   
2004-01-01          4827         3459     1368.0          4552         3153   
2005-01-01          5207         3670     1537.0          4876         3358   

           difference  
2001-01-01      532.0  
2002-01-01     1158.0  
2003-01-01     1221.0  
2004-01-01     1399.0  
2005-01-01     1518.0
```

Comment: Very clever - but would this be a general solution for different operations? What if I wanted to compute the ratio, for example?

Comment: Let's see.  First, It takes time to work with your sample data because you didn't provide code to generate the dataframe.  So, I let you know what might work.  Since then, I've constructed your dataframe and I can experiment more.

Comment: Oh, in future, you can just copy the output behind `df.head()` and read it in using `pd.read_clipboard()`.

Comment: awe, that works huh?  don't know why I didn't try that.

Comment: @piRSquared I found better alternative of your solution, see my answer.

Comment: @FooBar - I think you can accept this answer, although I found better alternative.

Comment: @jezrael agreed, I chose `T` and stuck with it.

Comment: Yes, I once use `axis=1` and I try it - it works. :)

Comment: can I suggest the following, in order to keep the code more general (will work with more than two columns, for example): `pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df2.columns.get_level_values(0).unique(), ['difference']])`

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use [IndexSlice](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers):

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df[('Total private','difference')] = (df.loc[:, idx[('Total nonfarm', 'Hires')]] - 
                                      df.loc[:, idx[('Total private', 'Hires')]])
print (df)
           Total nonfarm              Total private                        
date               Hires Job openings         Hires Job openings difference
2001-01-01          5777         5385          5419         4887        358
2002-01-01          4849         3759          4539         3381        310
2003-01-01          4971         3824          4645         3424        326
2004-01-01          4827         3459          4552         3153        275
2005-01-01          5207         3670          4876         3358        331
```

If you want multiple columns, you can use modified [piRSquared's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37490808/2901002) - you can remove transposing:

```
print (df.groupby(level=0,axis=1).diff(-1).dropna(1))
           Total nonfarm Total private             
date               Hires         Hires Job openings
2001-01-01         392.0         532.0       4495.0
2002-01-01        1090.0        1158.0       2291.0
2003-01-01        1147.0        1221.0       2277.0
2004-01-01        1368.0        1399.0       1785.0
2005-01-01        1537.0        1518.0       1821.0
```

Comment: I liked your first answer especially because it was not using `div()` or `diff()` hacks. What if there's more than two sub-columns and I specifically want to divide `Hires/Job openings`, and ignore a third column? Many of the suggestions here feel like they're very particular to the scenario, and not generally applicable. I feel like if in 10 days I have a similar issue, unless it's exactly what I had today, I didn't learn much that will help me with that issue

Comment: Thanks for upvote. What does mean 'more than two sub-columns'? Can you add sample? Now I have no time for you, but later I try help you.

Comment: Another column at level 1, for example to be generated via `df.loc[:, idx['Total nonfarm', 'foo']] = 15`

Answer (score 1):

Let's keep it simple.

```
In [19]: df['Total nonfarm'] - df['Total private']
Out[19]: 
            Hires  Job Openings
2001-01-01    358           498
2002-01-01    310           378
2003-01-01    326           400
2004-01-01    275           306
2005-01-01    331           312
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to go about this is to swap the column levels and use the column accessors.

#### Setup

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [5777, 5385, 5419, 4887],
        [4849, 3759, 4539, 3381],
        [4971, 3824, 4645, 3424],
        [4827, 3459, 4552, 3153],
        [5207, 3670, 4876, 3358],
    ],
    index=pd.to_datetime(['2001-01-01',
                          '2002-01-01',
                          '2003-01-01',
                          '2004-01-01',
                          '2005-01-01']),
    columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
        [('Total nonfarm', 'Hires'), ('Total nonfarm', 'Job Openings'),
         ('Total private', 'Hires'), ('Total private', 'Job Openings')]
    )
)

print df
           Total nonfarm              Total private             
                   Hires Job Openings         Hires Job Openings
2001-01-01          5777         5385          5419         4887
2002-01-01          4849         3759          4539         3381
2003-01-01          4971         3824          4645         3424
2004-01-01          4827         3459          4552         3153
2005-01-01          5207         3670          4876         3358
```

If we swap level then sort, it looks like:

```
print df.swaplevel(0, 1, 1).sort_index(axis=1)

                   Hires                Job Openings              
           Total nonfarm Total private Total nonfarm Total private
2001-01-01          5777          5419          5385          4887
2002-01-01          4849          4539          3759          3381
2003-01-01          4971          4645          3824          3424
2004-01-01          4827          4552          3459          3153
2005-01-01          5207          4876          3670          3358
```

With this we can access the Hires with `.Hires` or `['Hires']`.  Combining this with your need to subtract:

```
print df.swaplevel(0, 1, 1)['Hires']

            Total nonfarm  Total private
2001-01-01           5777           5419
2002-01-01           4849           4539
2003-01-01           4971           4645
2004-01-01           4827           4552
2005-01-01           5207           4876

print df.swaplevel(0, 1, 1)['Hires'] - df.swaplevel(0, 1, 1)['Job Openings']

            Total nonfarm  Total private
2001-01-01            392            532
2002-01-01           1090           1158
2003-01-01           1147           1221
2004-01-01           1368           1399
2005-01-01           1537           1518
```

#### Solution

Putting it all together with a little extra, I did:

```
df_ = df.swaplevel(0, 1, 1)

_df = pd.concat([
        df_,
        pd.concat([df_['Hires'] - df_['Job Openings'], df_['Hires'] / df_['Job Openings']],
                 axis=1, keys=['Difference', 'Ratio'])
    ], axis=1)

df = _df.swaplevel(0, 1, 1).sort_index(axis=1)

print df

           Total nonfarm                              Total private        \
              Difference Hires Job Openings     Ratio    Difference Hires   
2001-01-01           392  5777         5385  1.072795           532  5419   
2002-01-01          1090  4849         3759  1.289971          1158  4539   
2003-01-01          1147  4971         3824  1.299948          1221  4645   
2004-01-01          1368  4827         3459  1.395490          1399  4552   
2005-01-01          1537  5207         3670  1.418801          1518  4876   


           Job Openings     Ratio  
2001-01-01         4887  1.108860  
2002-01-01         3381  1.342502  
2003-01-01         3424  1.356600  
2004-01-01         3153  1.443704  
2005-01-01         3358  1.452055
```

---

You could also use `xs` to grab cross sections.

```
kw = dict(axis=1, level=1)

df.xs('Hires', **kw) - df.xs('Job Openings', **kw)

            Total nonfarm  Total private
2001-01-01            392            532
2002-01-01           1090           1158
2003-01-01           1147           1221
2004-01-01           1368           1399
2005-01-01           1537           1518
```

Comment: could the xs method be used to create a column in the multiindex dataframe such as in this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38352742/pandas-design-considerations-for-multiindexed-dataframes)?

Comment: IIUC, yes.  `xs` has a `drop_level=True` parameter that can be set to `False` thus preserving the multiindex.

Comment: my preference would be to use your `groupby` and `apply` however when I try to use for four levels it fails.  Why would that be?

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupby` and `apply`

#### Setup

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [5777, 5385, 5419, 4887],
        [4849, 3759, 4539, 3381],
        [4971, 3824, 4645, 3424],
        [4827, 3459, 4552, 3153],
        [5207, 3670, 4876, 3358],
    ],
    index=pd.to_datetime(['2001-01-01',
                          '2002-01-01',
                          '2003-01-01',
                          '2004-01-01',
                          '2005-01-01']),
    columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
        [('Total nonfarm', 'Hires'), ('Total nonfarm', 'Job Openings'),
         ('Total private', 'Hires'), ('Total private', 'Job Openings')]
    )
)

print df
```

#### Solution

```
def diff(group):
    g = group.shift().sub(group).dropna()
    g.index = ['Difference']
    return g

def ratio(group):
    g = group.shift().div(group).dropna()
    g.index = ['Ratio']
    return g

def do_nothing(group):
    return group

pd.concat(
    [df.T.groupby(level=0).apply(f).T for f in [diff, ratio, do_nothing]],
    axis=1
).sort_index(axis=1)

           Total nonfarm                          Total private        \
              Difference Hires Job Openings Ratio    Difference Hires   
2001-01-01         392.0  5777         5385  1.07         532.0  5419   
2002-01-01        1090.0  4849         3759  1.29        1158.0  4539   
2003-01-01        1147.0  4971         3824  1.30        1221.0  4645   
2004-01-01        1368.0  4827         3459  1.40        1399.0  4552   
2005-01-01        1537.0  5207         3670  1.42        1518.0  4876   


           Job Openings Ratio  
2001-01-01         4887  1.11  
2002-01-01         3381  1.34  
2003-01-01         3424  1.36  
2004-01-01         3153  1.44  
2005-01-01         3358  1.45
```

Comment: Ive tried to assimilate the above [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38491990/adding-a-column-derived-from-apply-to-multiindex-dataframe-using-tshift) but cannot find the correct syntax. are you able to offer any input?