# Adding and Renaming a Column in a Multiindex DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The purpose of this post is to understand how to add a column to a level in a `MultiIndex.DataFrame` using `apply()` and `shift()`

**Create the DataFrame**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
[
    [5777, 100, 5385, 200, 5419, 4887, 100, 200],
    [4849, 0, 4539, 0, 3381, 0, 0, ],
    [4971, 0, 3824, 0, 4645, 3424, 0, 0, ],
    [4827, 200, 3459, 300, 4552, 3153, 100, 200, ],
    [5207, 0, 3670, 0, 4876, 3358, 0, 0, ],
],
index=pd.to_datetime(['2010-01-01',
                      '2010-01-02',
                      '2010-01-03',
                      '2010-01-04',
                      '2010-01-05']),
columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
    [('Portfolio A', 'GBP', 'amount'), ('Portfolio A', 'GBP', 'injection'),
     ('Portfolio B', 'EUR', 'amount'), ('Portfolio B', 'EUR', 'injection'),
     ('Portfolio A', 'USD', 'amount'), ('Portfolio A', 'USD', 'injection'),
     ('Portfolio B', 'JPY', 'amount'), ('Portfolio B', 'JPY', 'injection')])
).sortlevel(axis=1)

print df
```

I would like to use the following method to add a new column to each currency at level 2 named daily_added_value:

```
def do_nothing(group):
   return group

def calc_daily_added_value(group):
    g = (group['amount'] - group['amount'].shift(periods=1, freq=None, axis=0)
          -df['injection'].shift(periods=1, freq=None, axis=0)).round(decimals=2)
    g.index = ['daily_added_value']
    return g

pd.concat([df.T.groupby(level=0).apply(f).T for f in [calc_daily_added_value,do_nothing ]], axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
```

However this throws a key error: `KeyError: 'amount'`

What is the correct syntax for the method `calc_daily_added_value()`?

---

**Following on from the answer below there is still an issue**

**Adding the daily return works**

```
dav = df.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, :, 'daily_added_value']]
amount = df.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, :, 'amount']]
dr = (dav.values / amount.shift()) * 100
dr.columns.set_levels(['daily_return'], level=2, inplace=True)
df = pd.concat([df, dr], axis=1).sortlevel(axis=1)
```

**Adding the cumulative compounded returns FAILS**

```
dr = df.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, :, 'daily_return']]
drc = 100*((1+dr / 100).cumprod()-1)
drc.columns.set_levels(['daily_return_cumulative'], level=2, inplace=True)
df = pd.concat([df, drc], axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
df.head()
```

this fails because it is missing the .values, but if I add this it becomes an array?

What is strange here though is that drc is in fact a DataFrame of correct shaped etc. and appears to contain correct results.

This fails on this line:

```
drc.columns.set_levels(['daily_return_cumulative'], level=2, inplace=True)
```

Error is `ValueError: On level 2, label max (2) >= length of level  (1). NOTE: this index is in an inconsistent state`

**How can the index be placed back into a consistent state?**

Comment: The failing command can be changed to `drc.columns.set_levels(['daily_return_cumulative'], level=2, inplace=True, verify_integrity = False)` however this yields an `algos.cp35-win_amd64.pyd` **unhandled exception**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skip the `groupby` it is not necessary

```
amount = df.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, :, 'amount']]
inject = df.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, :, 'injection']]
dav = amount - amount.shift() - inject.shift().values
#dav.columns.set_levels(['daily_added_value'], level=2, inplace=True)

pd.concat([df, dav], axis=1).sort_index(axis=1).T
```

#### Note: I used `T` to get a picture that would easily fit

[image]

there appears to be a [bug](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/13754) in `set_levels` and as such it is not advised to use it.

**Workaround to rename the MultiIndex Column in the DataFrame dav**

```
def map_level(df, dct, level=2):
    index = df.index
    index.set_levels([[dct.get(item, item) for item in names] if i==level else    names
                       for i, names in enumerate(index.levels)], inplace=True)
dct = {'amount':'daily_added_value'}
map_level(dav.T, dct, level=2)
```

Comment: I like the simplicity of this.  Given the `dav` and the `amount`, I now want to calculate the daily return dav.shift(-1) / amount.  So start point for calculation is  `dav on 2010-01-02 / amount on 2010-01-01` however if I do this I get error:  `ValueError: On level 2, label max (1) >= length of level  (1). NOTE: this index is in an inconsistent state`   Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: I have resolved this with `dr = (dav / mtm.shift().values) * 100 `

Comment: however when I attempt to use `drc = 100*((1+dr / 100).cumprod()-1)` I get the error again when I try to set_level.  I will edit the question with full details.

Comment: Note that the bug metioned above around `set_levels` was fixed in `Pandas 0.19.1`