# Better way for creating columns in a multi level columns pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Supposing that I have a pandas multi level columns data-frame `df` like this:

```
  | A     |  B     -> first level
---------------------------------
  | x  y  |  x   y -> second level
---------------------------------
0|  5  5  |  1   5
1|  3  1  |  4   7
2|  1  4  |  10  20
3| 50  8  |  7   8
```

How can I create a new column with the difference between x and y for each level?

I know that I could do one by one, like this:

```
df["A"]["diff"] = df["A"].x - df["A"].y
df["B"]["diff"] = df["B"].x - df["B"].y
```

The final output would be:

```
  | A          |  B            -> first level
-----------------------------------------------
  | x  y  diff |  x   y   diff -> second level
-----------------------------------------------
0|  5  5  0    |  1   5   -4
1|  3  1  2    |  4   7   -3
2|  1  4  -3   |  10  20  -10
3| 50  8  42   |  7   8   -1
```

Is there a one line operation to apply this column creation for all levels at once?

My solution this seems very repetitive, and in my case I may have several (more than 10 labels) at first level).

Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: `df.groupby(level=0,axis=1).diff(-1).dropna(1)` ??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37490717/pandas-apply-operation-to-repetitive-columns-in-multiindex

Answer (score 2):

sample df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3], [7,8,9,10,11,12,7,8,9], [13,14,15,16,17,18,4,5,6]], index=pd.date_range('2004-01-01', '2004-01-03'))
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['x', 'y', 'z'], list('abc')])
```

**df:**

|  | x |  |  | y |  |  | z |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | a | b | c | a | b | c | a | b | c |
| 2004-01-01 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2004-01-02 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| 2004-01-03 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 4 | 5 | 6 |

---

```
df1 = df.sum(level=0, axis=1)
df1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df1.columns,["sum"]])
df1 = pd.concat([df,df1],axis=1).sort_index(1)
```

---

**df1:**

|  | x |  |  |  | y |  |  |  | z |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | a | b | c | sum | a | b | c | sum | a | b | c | sum |
| 2004-01-01 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 6 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 15 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 6 |
| 2004-01-02 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 24 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 33 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 24 |
| 2004-01-03 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 42 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 51 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 15 |

### Edit:

**Subtraction:**

```
df2 = df.T.groupby(level=[0]).diff().T.loc[:,df.columns.get_level_values(1).isin(['c'])]
df2 = pd.concat([df,df2.rename(columns={'c':'diff b/w b and c'})],axis=1).sort_index(1)
```

---

**df2:**

|  | x |  |  |  | y |  |  |  | z |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | a | b | c | diff b/w b and c | a | b | c | diff b/w b and c | a | b | c | diff b/w b and c |
| 2004-01-01 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 1.0 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 1.0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 1.0 |
| 2004-01-02 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 1.0 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 1.0 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 1.0 |
| 2004-01-03 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 1.0 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 1.0 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 1.0 |

### Edit(Final optimized):

```
df2 = (df.T.groupby(level=[0]).diff().T.rename(mapper=lambda x: f'diff_{x}', 
            axis='columns',
            level=1,
            ))
df2 = pd.concat([df,df2],axis=1).sort_index(1)
```

---

**df2:**

|  | x |  |  |  |  |  | y |  |  |  |  |  | z |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | a | b | c | diff_a | diff_b | diff_c | a | b | c | diff_a | diff_b | diff_c | a | b | c | diff_a | diff_b | diff_c |
| 2004-01-01 | 1 | 2 | 3 | NaN | 1.0 | 1.0 | 4 | 5 | 6 | NaN | 1.0 | 1.0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | NaN | 1.0 | 1.0 |
| 2004-01-02 | 7 | 8 | 9 | NaN | 1.0 | 1.0 | 10 | 11 | 12 | NaN | 1.0 | 1.0 | 7 | 8 | 9 | NaN | 1.0 | 1.0 |
| 2004-01-03 | 13 | 14 | 15 | NaN | 1.0 | 1.0 | 16 | 17 | 18 | NaN | 1.0 | 1.0 | 4 | 5 | 6 | NaN | 1.0 | 1.0 |

As mentioned by *Shubham Sharma* :)

You can use:

```
for c in df.columns.levels[0]:
    df.loc[:, (c, 'diff')] = df[(c, 'b')] - df[(c, 'a')]

df = df.sort_index(level=0, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a little reshaping and `pd.DataFrame.eval`, however sort_index does an alphabetical sort on column headers.

```
df.stack(0).eval('zdiff = x - y').unstack().swaplevel(0, 1, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    A            B          
    x  y zdiff   x   y zdiff
0                           
0   5  5     0   1   5    -4
1   3  1     2   4   7    -3
2   1  4    -3  10  20   -10
3  50  8    42   7   8    -1
```